# Replacing a character from mysql table to export to JSON file

Tags: mysql

I have a very long sized table (over 4M of records,i work with MySql) and it has a lot of records with this string: **\\"**

I'm trying to export this table to mongodb, but when I import the JSON file mongodb throws to me this error:

> > Failed: error processing document #18: invalid character 't' after object key:value pair

this is my query:
MySQL

```
SELECT json_object(
     "id", id,
     "execution_id", execution_id,
     "type", type,
     "info", info,
     "position", position,
     "created_at", json_object("$date", DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')),
     "updated_at", json_object("$date", DATE_FORMAT(updated_at,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'))
      )as 'json'
      FROM myTable
      INTO OUTFILE 'myPath';
```

I know the problem is the string, my question is: how can I change this certain string to **\"**? Manually change it´s not an option, and my knowledge about query is limited. Please help. Thank you for reading me .

The column that has this character is "info", here is an example:

```
{
    "id": 30, 
    "execution_id": 2, 
    "type": "PHASE", 
    "info": "{  \\r\\n \\"title\\": \\"Phase\\",
                \\r\\n \\"order\\": \\"1\\",
                \\r\\n \\"description\\": \\"Example Phase 1\\",
                \\r\\n \\"step\\": \\"end\\",
                \\r\\n \\"status\\": \\"True\\"\\r\\n}",
    "position": 24, 
    "created_at": {"$date": "2018-01-11T15:01:46Z"}, 
    "updated_at": {"$date": "2018-01-11T15:01:46Z"}
}
```

Comment: Ok Start by telling us which column has these `\\\` characters in. Then it would be useful to see a few examples of the column and then show us what you would like the end result to look like

Comment: It is always better to put that extra info into the question. It is so much easier to read that way

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the [MySQL `REPLACE()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

The backslash is a bit of a special case in the MySQL `REPLACE()` function, so you will need to use `\\` to represent each literal `\`, thus to replace `\\` with `\` you need to run something like this:

`REPLACE(info,'\\\\','\\')`

Your full query would look something like this:

```
SELECT json_object(
     "id", id,
     "execution_id", execution_id,
     "type", type,
     "info", REPLACE(info,'\\\\','\\'),
     "position", position,
     "created_at", json_object("$date", DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')),
     "updated_at", json_object("$date", DATE_FORMAT(updated_at,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'))
      )as 'json'
      FROM myTable
      INTO OUTFILE 'myPath';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but it doesn't work for me, the query throw this error:
ERROR 1583 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'json_object'